# Getting error at PieData data = new PieData(labels, dataset); while adding data

Tags: android, graph, charts, mpandroidchart

In my app there is a need of pie chart for which i am using MPAndroidChart but, getting error while adding data in Piedata constructor,please help.
Using dependancy  compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0 beta'

```
 imageView=(PieChart) v.findViewById(R.id.result_text);
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new Entry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new Entry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new Entry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new Entry(12f, 3));
    entries.add(new Entry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new Entry(9f, 5));
    PieDataSet dataset = new PieDataSet(entries,"uyggh");
    ArrayList<Object> labels = new ArrayList<Object>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");
    PieData data = new PieData(labels, dataset);//getting error here
    imageView.setData(data);
    imageView.setDescription("Description");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PieData` takes only one argument and that is `PieDataSet`. So replace

```
PieData data = new PieData(labels, dataset);
```

with

```
PieData data = new PieData(dataset);
```

For more details, you can check [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java) official example.

**Hope, this answer is helpful to you.**

Comment: PieData support only just one dataSet?

Answer (score 6):

Acoording to the latest documentation corresponding to [com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data) , entries (Pie Entries) now take x and y values together.

```
List<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

entries.add(new PieEntry(18.5f, "Green"));
entries.add(new PieEntry(26.7f, "Yellow"));
entries.add(new PieEntry(24.0f, "Red"));
entries.add(new PieEntry(30.8f, "Blue")); 

PieDataSet set = new PieDataSet(entries, "Election Results");
PieData data = new PieData(set);
pieChart.setData(data);
pieChart.invalidate(); // refresh
```

So instead of degrading the depandency , use the updated code.

Comment: I was expecting to provide the same solution but i found this is the same solution am using. This is it

Answer (score 1):

When i used dependancy com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6' then 
PieData accepts two arguments i.e String and PieDataSet. So, I think its problem with the dependancy update.
Using lower dependancy it can be solve.

Comment: That what I have said about arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You should passing  labels in PieEntry methode like this.
it works for me

```
private  float[] yData = {25.3f,10.3f,66.3f,44.3f,16.3f,46.3f,23.3f};
private  String[] xData = {"med","hamza","mohammed","","","",""};

    for(int i = 0 ; i <yData.length;i++){
        yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i],xData[i % xData.length]));
```

### }

it's my code ,  it works 100 % with 
`compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'` But higher version of gradle use `implementation` instead of `compile`

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private  static  String TAG = "MainActivit";
private  float[] yData = {25.3f,10.3f,66.3f,44.3f,16.3f,46.3f,23.3f};
    private  String[] xData = {"med","hamza","mohammed","","","",""};
```

PieChart pieChart;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Log.d(TAG, "Beach chart");


        pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.idPieChart);
        //pieChart.setDescription(" Sales by employee In thousands $");
        pieChart.setRotationEnabled(true);
        pieChart.setHoleRadius(25f);
        pieChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(0);
        pieChart.setCenterText("super cool chart");
        pieChart.setCenterTextSize(10);
        pieChart.setDrawEntryLabels(true);

        addDataSet();


        pieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: value selected from chart");
                Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: "+ e.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: "+ h.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {

            }
        });
    }

    private void addDataSet() {
        Log.d(TAG, "addDataSet: started");

        ArrayList<PieEntry> yEntrys = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> xEntrys = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0 ; i <yData.length;i++){
            yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i],xData[i % xData.length]));

 }

        for(int i = 0 ; i <xData.length;i++){
            xEntrys.add(xData[i]);

        }


        //create the DATA

        PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(yEntrys,"Beachs");
        pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(2);
        pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);



        //add colors to dataSet

        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add(Color.GRAY);
        colors.add(Color.BLUE);
        colors.add(Color.RED);
        colors.add(Color.GREEN);
        colors.add(Color.CYAN);
        colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
        colors.add(Color.MAGENTA);

        pieDataSet.setColors(colors);

pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(25);



        //add legend to chart

        Legend legend = pieChart.getLegend();
        legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE);
        legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.LEFT_OF_CHART);


        //create a pieData object

        PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);



        pieChart.setData(pieData);

pieChart.invalidate();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ArryayList<> should be with String, not with Object:

```
ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
....
PieData data = new PieData(labels, dataset);//getting error here
```

Because new PieData needs ArrayList<< String >>